# cache-friendliest way to initialize a struct from an enum argument associated with necessary data?

Tags: c++, caching, contiguous, entity-component-system, data-oriented-design

In my ECS game engine, my SpriteComponent has a constructor where the sole argument is an enum-type that represents a specific "instance" of the struct.

ex:
the enum `REDMAGIC` is associated with the SpriteComponent struct values: `{x,y,z}`

These SpriteComponents are added to Entities at runtime for example when a player is shooting. To me, this means I want to construct SpriteComponents in the most cache-friendly way possible.

I have 3 approaches in mind:

1. use a hashtable to get data and then assign to my new SpriteComponent
   ex: `std::unordered_map<enum, {x,y,z}>`
2. use a vector or array to get data and then assign to my new SpriteComponent
   ex: `std::vector<{x,y,z}>`
3. manually assign values with a bunch of case or if statements:

   ```
    switch(enum){
        case REDMAGIC:
             x = 1;
             y = 2;
             z = 3;
        case BLUEMAGIC:
             ...
   ```

I am new to data-oriented design and do not know how to reason about which approach would be best for cache-friendliness. I am concerned about using switch/case or a lot of if statements because there will be over 100 different possibilities. any input would be appreciate, thank you.

Comment: Are the values stored in the lookup compile time constants?